# Python PyQT/Seaborn - Interactive charts, keyboard arrow controls and speed

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm creating a interactive chart with the seaborn package.
It's a simple chart with dates on the x axis and value from 0 to 5 on the y axis
I can move a cursor-bar over it left and right, with arrow keys and set the y value of the chart with num keys (and export to csv the charts y values with their timestamp).
However when large date ranges are used the program becomes incredibly slow.
I press the arrow keys to move the cursor one bar but it can take one or 2 seconds to react. (the key control are done with PyQT) 
Any idea what i might do to speed it up?

Please feel free to copy paste the code and run it in python to see the program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, date
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import matplotlib.lines
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import csv
from itertools import izip



dates = []
values = []

sns.set(style="ticks")

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(25,7))
fig.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.ylim(0,5)

horizontal_position = 0

periods = 365
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01', freq='d', periods=periods)
index_delete = []
for i in range(idx.size):
    if idx[i].dayofweek == 6 or idx[i].dayofweek == 5:
        index_delete.append(i)
idx = idx.delete(index_delete)
periods = idx.size

idx_x_array = np.array(range(idx.size), dtype=np.int32)

str_vals = []
first_day_lines = []
counter = 0
if periods > 170:
    for s in idx._data:
        s = str(s)
        day = s[8:10]
        month = s[5:7]
        year = s[0:4]
        if day == '01':
            dotted_line_f = plt.Line2D((counter, counter), (0, 5), lw=2., marker='.',
                                       color='gray')
            first_day_lines.append(dotted_line_f)
            date_str = day+'/'+month+'/'+year
            str_vals.append(date_str)
        elif idx.dayofweek[counter]:
            date_str = day+'/'+month
            str_vals.append(date_str)
        else:
            str_vals.append('')
        counter +=1
if periods <= 170:
    for s in idx._data:
        s = str(s)
        day = s[8:10]
        month = s[5:7]
        year = s[0:4]
        if day == '01':
            dotted_line_f = plt.Line2D((counter, counter), (0, 5), lw=2., marker='.',
                                       color='gray')
            first_day_lines.append(dotted_line_f)
            date_str = day+'/'+month+'/'+year
            str_vals.append(date_str)
        else:
            date_str = day+'/'+month
            str_vals.append(date_str)
        counter +=1
plt.grid(True)

plt.xticks(idx_x_array, str_vals, rotation='vertical', fontsize=7)
values = []
for i in idx_x_array:
    values.append(0)

data= pd.DataFrame({('A','a'):values}, idx)
sns.set_context(context={"figure.figsize":(5,5)})
ab = sns.tsplot(data.T.values, idx_x_array)
ab.lines[0].set_color('red')
# x_len = len(ab.lines[0]._x)
ab.lines[0]._x = idx_x_array
dotted_line = plt.Line2D((1, 1), (0, 5), lw=2.,
                         ls='-.', marker='.',
                         markersize=1,
                         color='black',
                         markerfacecolor='black',
                         markeredgecolor='black',
                         alpha=0.5)
ab.add_line(dotted_line)
for line in first_day_lines:
    ab.add_line(line)

lines = ab.lines
init_focus = ab.lines[0]
index_focus = 0



bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="rarrow,pad=0.3", fc="pink", ec="b", lw=2)
horizontal_position = init_focus._x[index_focus]
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.30, left=.03, right=.97, top=.90, hspace=.35)

analysis_label = 'Analysis mode'
discovery_label = 'Discovery mode'


def chart_mode(event):
    global button_label
    global dotted_line
    global power
    global horizontal_position
    global index_focus
    global dotted_line
    global idx
    if button_label == analysis_label:
        index_focus = 0
        button_label = discovery_label
        plt.draw()
    elif button_label == discovery_label:
        index_focus = periods-1
        button_label = analysis_label
        plt.draw()
    bnext.label.set_text(button_label)
    horizontal_position = ab.lines[0]._x[index_focus]
    dotted_line = plt.Line2D((horizontal_position,horizontal_position), (0, 5), lw=5.,
                             ls='-.', marker='.',
                             markersize=1,
                             color='black',
                             markerfacecolor='black',
                             markeredgecolor='black',
                             alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_line(dotted_line)
    new_line = ax.lines.pop()
    ax.lines[1] = new_line

def export_csv(event):
    x_data = idx._data
    y_data = ab.lines[0]._y
    x_data_proc = []
    for x in x_data:
        x = str(x)
        day = x[8:10]
        month = x[5:7]
        year = x[0:4]
        date_str = day+'/'+month
        x_data_proc.append(date_str)
    y_data_proc = []
    for y in y_data:
        y_data_proc.append(int(y))
    with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(izip(x_data_proc, y_data_proc))

button_label = analysis_label
axnext = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, button_label)
bnext.on_clicked(chart_mode)

axexport = plt.axes([0.21, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bexport = Button(axexport, 'export csv')
bexport.on_clicked(export_csv)

def on_keyboard(event):
    global power
    global horizontal_position
    global index_focus
    global dotted_line
    global idx
    if event.key == 'right':
        if index_focus < periods-1:
            index_focus+=1
        else:
            idx = idx + timedelta(days=1)
            index_focus+=1
    elif event.key == 'left':
        if index_focus > 0:
            index_focus-=1
    elif event.key == 'up':
        if index_focus < periods-5:
            index_focus+=5
    elif event.key == 'down':
        if index_focus > 5:
            index_focus-=5

    elif is_number(event.key):
        for i in range(len(ab.lines[0]._y[index_focus::])):
            ab.lines[0]._y[index_focus+i] = event.key

    horizontal_position = ab.lines[0]._x[index_focus]
    dotted_line = plt.Line2D((horizontal_position,horizontal_position), (0, 5), lw=2.,
                             ls='-.', marker='.',
                             markersize=1,
                             color='black',
                             markerfacecolor='black',
                             markeredgecolor='black',
                             alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_line(dotted_line)
    new_line = ax.lines.pop()
    ax.lines[1] = new_line
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.show()

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_keyboard)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this code is too long for me to plough through.
Nonetheless, a couple of easy ways to help find bottlenecks:

- interrupt the slow program, and look at the stack trace; repeat 5 times.
  In your case these will have lots of incomprehensible calls in Qt4 etc.,
  but you might be able to see what your code is calling that's slow.
- good old `print`: add e.g. `print "%.3f %s" % (time.time() - t0, event.key)` in `on_keyboard` .
  Then, comment out the drawing stuff, print only, run blind: is the time spent in drawing,
  or somewhere else ?

Also, why `Qt4Agg` -- is `TkAgg` just as slow ?
Also, what does "when large date ranges are used" mean  -- how large ?